# NSFetchedResultController EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 2

Tags: ios, core-data

i am working on a chat application using xmpp framework on iOS, i am working now with the Roster Storage that is giving by the framework itself, i get this error just when i run the application, log in with my account, and it suddenly crashes, i tried to debug it but i can't find an explanation. here is the code:

```
@interface FriendListTableViewController ()<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultController;

@end

@implementation FriendListTableViewController


-(AppDelegate *)appDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
}

#pragma mark - FetchedResult Controller delegate

-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultController
{
    if (self.fetchedResultController == nil) { //Here is the EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2

        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext_roster];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoraDataStorageObject" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDes1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNum" ascending:YES];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDes2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDes1,sortDes2, nil];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

        self.fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNum" cacheName:nil];

        [self.fetchedResultController setDelegate:self];

        NSError *error = nil;

        if (![self.fetchedResultController performFetch:&error]) {

        }

    }

    return self.fetchedResultController;
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing a getter method, `fetchedResultController` (although I would name it `fetchedResultsController`, to match the class name. And then within that getter method you're calling `self.fetchedResultController` (reinvoking the getter within itself) and later `self.fetchedResultController = ...`, invoking the setter within the getter.

Within the setter/getter methods is the only place where you should be using the backing ivar directly.

A better idiom:
In .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController
```

And then in .m

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_!fetchedResultsController) {

        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext_roster;

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoraDataStorageObject" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDes1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNum" ascending:YES];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDes2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDes1, sortDes2];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                              initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                              managedObjectContext:moc          
                                sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNum" 
                                        cacheName:nil];

        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        NSError *error = nil;

        if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
              NSAssert(NO, @"fetchedResultsController fetch failed");
        }

    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

A couple of other notes: I modernized your array initialization syntax. I also suggest you keep your MOC reference local, instead of reaching back to the app delegate to find it. Your mixed use of dot and bracket notation makes your code harder to read; consider `fetchRequest.entity = entity`, etc. And finally, using those hardcoded string keypaths (`sectionNum`, `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject`, etc) within your code is asking for a hard-to-find bug. Define them once as `extern` strings.

Comment: That means that the entity you asked for (`entityForName:`) doesn't exist in your Core Data model file, or perhaps that your MOC hasn't been initialized correctly. For paranoia's sake, consider adding `NSParameterAssert(entity)` and `NSParameterAssert(moc)` to make those calls fail immediately when there's a problem, instead of triggering the late error you're seeing now.

Comment: Ok, now it appears to work fine! however, i am not populating the tableview with the list of friends! but i am not getting any error either! i am just getting the object from coredata and using displayName to get the name! hope you can help me @Hal Mueller

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your datastore? A way to check that would be, after you initialize your fetch request, to call `NSLog(@"%@", [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error])` and see if you get any results. That takes the FRC and table view out of the chain.

Comment: Hi Hal, thanks for your replies, it surely is not printing anything, i put it just after return the _fetchedResultsController, but i can't see anything, but isn't it supposed to be autofetched?

Comment: That tells you that your MOC is not finding any data. So your datastore is empty, or your MOC is not being initialized correctly. This is down to old fashioned debugging now: walk through step by step, and verify your Core Data stack initialization, your record insertion/save, and your fetch requests. Make sure all of that is right before worrying about the FRC.

Comment: Ok, maybe i am not asking for the roster, i checked my code and well, i think i am not implementing any method to get it, or xmpp framework do this in background?

Comment: Hello Hal, i would like to ask you some things! about xmpp and of course iOS, i hope we can get a little talk trough s ky pe or something like it! i will really appreciate your kind help, i have some questions that users here just tend to tell they are to broad or something but i need a proper advice and guidance.

Comment: Contact me via email and I'll try to point you in the right direction. For Core Data fundamentals, I'm currently a fan of Tim Roadley's book "Learning Core Data for iOS".